# Table out of margin

Tags: tables, margins, siunitx

I created this table using `siunitx` package since values must to be represented in scientific notation. Unfortunately the table goes out of margin. How can I fix the issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
    \sisetup{table-format=1.4e06,exponent-product = \cdot}
    \begin{tabular}{lSSSSS}
        \toprule
        {\emph{Nodi}}      &        \multicolumn{5}{c}{Sistemi di trasmissione}        \\
        \cmidrule{2-6} &    {BC}    & {$\text{PNC}_{16}$} & {$\text{PNC}_{32}$} & {{$\text{PNC}_{64}$}} & {$\text{PNC}_{128}$} \\ \midrule
        1                  & 1.4307e-06 &  2.4116e-05  &  4.6601e-05  &   9.145e-05    &  1.9019e-04   \\
        3                  & 2,108e-06  &  2.5738e-05  &  5.1332e-05  &   9.775e-05    &  1.9374e-04   \\
        7                  & 2.7708e-06 &  2.7964e-05  &  5.324e-05   &   1.0158e-04   &  2.0066e-04   \\
        12                 & 3.2206e-06 &  2.905e-05   &  5.5356e-05  &   1.0441e-04   &  2.0528e-04   \\
        20                 & 3.6241e-06 &  2.9865e-05  &  5.6242e-05  &   1.0698e-04   &  2.0324e-04   \\
        25                 & 3.8909e-06 &  3.0289e-05  &  5.614e-05   &   1.0648e-04   &  2.0663e-04   \\
        35                 & 4.2468e-06 &  3.1154e-05  &  5.7399e-05  &   1.0791e-04   &  2.0598e-04   \\
        50                 & 4.4803e-06 &  3.1883e-05  &  5.8366e-05  &   1.0964e-04   &  2.0811e-04   \\
        65                 & 4.7681e-06 &  3.2091e-05  &  5.8808e-05  &   1.1044e-04   &  2.0992e-04   \\
        75                 & 4.9844e-06 &  3.2443e-05  &  5.9032e-05  &   1.099e-04    &  2.1003e-04   \\
        90                 & 5.1003e-06 &  3.2914e-05  &  5.9188e-05  &   1.1086e-04   &  2.0996e-04   \\
        100                & 5.2175e-06 &  3.3087e-05  &  5.9855e-05  &   1.1089e-04   &  2.1143e-04   \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: put \small before the tabular?

Comment: Please always post complete documents showing all packages used, it makes it _much_ easier to process locally and see (in this cas)e how far into the margin it is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I inserted \small. The table became smaller but is still out of margins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table fits in the margins, without need of setting `\small` and of reducing too much `\tabcolsep` with the following code. Note the

```
table-format=1.4e-1
```

key, which states precisely the space you need. This means:

- one digit for the integer part
- four decimal digits
- the sign for the exponent part
- one digit for the exponent

Your `table-format=1.4e06` reserved six digits for the exponent.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4e-1,exponent-product = \cdot}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{rSSSSS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{Nodi}} &
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{Sistemi di trasmissione} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
 & {BC} &
 {$\text{PNC}_{16}$} &
 {$\text{PNC}_{32}$} &
 {$\text{PNC}_{64}$} &
 {$\text{PNC}_{128}$} \\
\midrule
  1         & 1.4307e-06 &  2.4116e-05  &  4.6601e-05  &   9.145e-05    &  1.9019e-04   \\
  3         & 2,108e-06  &  2.5738e-05  &  5.1332e-05  &   9.775e-05    &  1.9374e-04   \\
  7         & 2.7708e-06 &  2.7964e-05  &  5.324e-05   &   1.0158e-04   &  2.0066e-04   \\
 12         & 3.2206e-06 &  2.905e-05   &  5.5356e-05  &   1.0441e-04   &  2.0528e-04   \\
 20         & 3.6241e-06 &  2.9865e-05  &  5.6242e-05  &   1.0698e-04   &  2.0324e-04   \\
 25         & 3.8909e-06 &  3.0289e-05  &  5.614e-05   &   1.0648e-04   &  2.0663e-04   \\
 35         & 4.2468e-06 &  3.1154e-05  &  5.7399e-05  &   1.0791e-04   &  2.0598e-04   \\
 50         & 4.4803e-06 &  3.1883e-05  &  5.8366e-05  &   1.0964e-04   &  2.0811e-04   \\
 65         & 4.7681e-06 &  3.2091e-05  &  5.8808e-05  &   1.1044e-04   &  2.0992e-04   \\
 75         & 4.9844e-06 &  3.2443e-05  &  5.9032e-05  &   1.099e-04    &  2.1003e-04   \\
 90         & 5.1003e-06 &  3.2914e-05  &  5.9188e-05  &   1.1086e-04   &  2.0996e-04   \\
100         & 5.2175e-06 &  3.3087e-05  &  5.9855e-05  &   1.1089e-04   &  2.1143e-04   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, the table width is 413.00468pt, while the `\textwidth` is
412.56499pt, so the difference is .44pt, less than the `\hfuzz` value of 0.5pt (0.18mm).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4e06,exponent-product = \cdot}
\begin{tabular}{@{\kern-1pt}lSSSSS@{\kern-1pt}}
    \toprule
    {\emph{Nodi}}      &        \multicolumn{5}{c}{Sistemi di trasmissione}        \\
    \cmidrule{2-6} &    {BC}    & {$\text{PNC}_{16}$} & {$\text{PNC}_{32}$} & {{$\text{PNC}_{64}$}} & {$\text{PNC}_{128}$} \\ \midrule
    1                  & 1.4307e-06 &  2.4116e-05  &  4.6601e-05  &   9.145e-05    &  1.9019e-04   \\
    3                  & 2,108e-06  &  2.5738e-05  &  5.1332e-05  &   9.775e-05    &  1.9374e-04   \\
    7                  & 2.7708e-06 &  2.7964e-05  &  5.324e-05   &   1.0158e-04   &  2.0066e-04   \\
    12                 & 3.2206e-06 &  2.905e-05   &  5.5356e-05  &   1.0441e-04   &  2.0528e-04   \\
    20                 & 3.6241e-06 &  2.9865e-05  &  5.6242e-05  &   1.0698e-04   &  2.0324e-04   \\
    25                 & 3.8909e-06 &  3.0289e-05  &  5.614e-05   &   1.0648e-04   &  2.0663e-04   \\
    35                 & 4.2468e-06 &  3.1154e-05  &  5.7399e-05  &   1.0791e-04   &  2.0598e-04   \\
    50                 & 4.4803e-06 &  3.1883e-05  &  5.8366e-05  &   1.0964e-04   &  2.0811e-04   \\
    65                 & 4.7681e-06 &  3.2091e-05  &  5.8808e-05  &   1.1044e-04   &  2.0992e-04   \\
    75                 & 4.9844e-06 &  3.2443e-05  &  5.9032e-05  &   1.099e-04    &  2.1003e-04   \\
    90                 & 5.1003e-06 &  3.2914e-05  &  5.9188e-05  &   1.1086e-04   &  2.0996e-04   \\
    100                & 5.2175e-06 &  3.3087e-05  &  5.9855e-05  &   1.1089e-04   &  2.1143e-04   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After may years ... seems to be useful (my) answer on question [how-to-make-a-column-specifier-which-combines-x-and-s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342564/how-to-make-a-column-specifier-which-combines-x-and-s), which was asked far later. Its adoption to this question is below.

Combination of `tabularx` table environment with combination of `X` (used for column headers in command `\multicolumn{1}{... X}{...}`) and `S` columns gives table width equal to text width and align of numbers as according to `S` column type:

[image]

(red lines show borders of page layout).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{showframe}% in real document had to be removed
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}%[htp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{S[table-format=3.0]
                            *{5}{S[table-number-alignment = center,
                                   exponent-product       = \cdot,
                                   table-figures-integer  = 1,
                                   table-figures-decimal  = 4,
                                   table-figures-exponent = 1]}
                                }
    \toprule
{\multirow{2}{*}{\emph{Nodi}}}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{Sistemi di trasmissione}        \\
    \cmidrule{2-6} 
    & \mcx{BC}   & \mcx{PNC$_{16}$} & \mcx{PNC$_{32}$}  & \mcx{PNC$_{64}$} & \mcx{PNC$_{128}$}  \\ \midrule
1   & 1.4307e-06 & 2.4116e-05       & 4.6601e-05        & 9.145e-05         & 1.9019e-04        \\
3   & 2,108e-06  & 2.5738e-05       & 5.1332e-05        & 9.775e-05         &  1.9374e-04       \\
7   & 2.7708e-06 & 2.7964e-05       & 5.324e-05         & 1.0158e-04        &  2.0066e-04       \\
12  & 3.2206e-06 & 2.905e-05        & 5.5356e-05        & 1.0441e-04        &  2.0528e-04       \\
20  & 3.6241e-06 & 2.9865e-05       & 5.6242e-05        & 1.0698e-04        &  2.0324e-04       \\
25  & 3.8909e-06 & 3.0289e-05       & 5.614e-05         & 1.0648e-04        &  2.0663e-04       \\
35  & 4.2468e-06 & 3.1154e-05       & 5.7399e-05        & 1.0791e-04        &  2.0598e-04       \\
50  & 4.4803e-06 & 3.1883e-05       & 5.8366e-05        & 1.0964e-04        &  2.0811e-04       \\
65  & 4.7681e-06 & 3.2091e-05       & 5.8808e-05        & 1.1044e-04        &  2.0992e-04       \\
75  & 4.9844e-06 & 3.2443e-05       & 5.9032e-05        & 1.099e-04         &  2.1003e-04       \\
90  & 5.1003e-06 & 3.2914e-05       & 5.9188e-05        & 1.1086e-04        &  2.0996e-04       \\
100 & 5.2175e-06 & 3.3087e-05       & 5.9855e-05        & 1.1089e-04        &  2.1143e-04       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```