# table out of margin: any suggestion?

Tags: tables, margins

I try to put a very large table inside a pdf:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
   \caption{ \textit{Title}. Some comments.}
    \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
    \hline
    Parameter       & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & eeeee & fffff & gggggg & hhhhh \\ \hline
    Parameter 1     & 111111  & 111111  & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 \\
    Parameter 2     & 0.0    & 0.0   & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0      \\
    Parameter 3   & 0.0    & 0.0   & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0        \\
    Parameter 4   & 444444  & 444444  & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 \\
     Parameter ...   & .....  & .....  & ..... & ..... & ..... & ..... & ..... \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

I read the help in [Table out of margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91232/table-out-of-margin) but I can't be able to found a very simple way to show this table because also in this case the table go out from the margin. Maybe I make some mistakes using `\sisetup{table-format=1.4e06,exponent-product = \cdot}`.

Can You help me to found a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, *this* one doesn't go into the margin, so it's hard to say what's the best solution. Please give a MWE.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what the problem is here. Can you include a MWE and maybe a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As one option, you can use `adjustbox` package and provide `max width` as `1.1\textwidth`. Then the table is restricted to that width only if it is wider than `1.1\textwidth`. Also use `center` option to center that table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{ \textit{Title}. Some comments.}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.1\textwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\hline
Parameter    & bbbbbb  & cccccc & dddddd & eeeee  & fffff  & gggggg & hhhhh  \\ \hline
Parameter 1  & 111111  & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 \\
Parameter 2  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 3  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 4  & 444444  & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 \\
Parameter ...& .....   & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since your table is not wider than `1.1\textwidth`, it is not resized.

Another option is to use `\makebox`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{ \textit{Title}. Some comments.}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\hline
Parameter    & bbbbbb  & cccccc & dddddd & eeeee  & fffff  & gggggg & hhhhh  \\ \hline
Parameter 1  & 111111  & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 \\
Parameter 2  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 3  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 4  & 444444  & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 \\
Parameter ...& .....   & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A good way to easily identify bad boxes is to use the draft option of most document classes, which prints a black box to the right of every overful box.

The code below shows you where is the bad box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{ \textit{Title}. Some comments.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}   
\hline
Parameter    & bbbbbb  & cccccc & dddddd & eeeee  & fffff  & gggggg & hhhhh  \\ \hline
Parameter 1  & 111111  & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 \\
Parameter 2  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 3  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 4  & 444444  & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 \\
Parameter ...& .....   & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The overful boxes are indicated by black boxes to the right as this:

[image]

The error message says:

```
Overfull \hbox (24.80644pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--16
```

In this case you can simply make room for 25pt extra space without making the table smaller. I choose 25pt as indicated by the error message. Here is how you do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{ \textit{Title}. Some comments.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}   
\hline
Parameter    & bbbbbb  & cccccc & dddddd & eeeee  & fffff  & gggggg & hhhhh  \\ \hline
Parameter 1  & 111111  & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 & 111111 \\
Parameter 2  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 3  & 0.0     & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    & 0.0    \\
Parameter 4  & 444444  & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 & 444444 \\
Parameter ...& .....   & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  & .....  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-25pt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table then looks like this (without any warnings):

[image]